# Excel VSTO AddIn and Context Menu idMso in "Page Break Preview" view mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsto, excel-interop

I've created an Excel 2010 AddIn using VSTO. I have a context menu which works fine, however when I switch to excel view "Page Break Preview", my right click context menu no longer shows. Is there a different idMso section that I need to define for page break mode?

I'm currently using:

```xml
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuCell">
        <!--buttons here-->
    </contextMenu>
```

Answer (score 5):

I found that there is a separate idMso for the "Page Break Preview" view. It is "ContextMenuCellLayout". The [ContextMenus Add-In for Office 2010](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/contextmenusaddin) came very much in handy to find it.

Comment: This has proven invaluable. Been tearing my hair out here. Thanks